# How to build URL in a Spring's @Scheduled task?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I want to build URL links to Controller methods. I use this method :

```
URI uri = MvcUriComponentsBuilder.fromMethodCall
(on(MyController.class).myMethod(...))
.build().encode().toUri();
```

to generate URL (to periodically send emails containing links , for example).

The problem is , when running inside Spring's @Scheduled task , it cannot get `RequestContext` , so it throws this exception :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find current request via RequestContextHolder
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:392)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder.getCurrentRequest(ServletUriComponentsBuilder.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentServletMapping(ServletUriComponentsBuilder.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.MvcUriComponentsBuilder.getBaseUrlToUse(MvcUriComponentsBuilder.java:412)
```

If in test environment , this can be solved by injecting `MockHttpServletRequest` , but it doesn't work because this is not in the a environment.

How to solve it ?

I googled and got some workarounds such as hard-coded scheme and host to build the URL , but I don't want to hard-code any host name , is there any other dynamic solutions ?

environments :

```
spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.4.3.RELEASE
spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you have no request available in a scheduled job as it is not triggered by any. IMHO you have only one option:

Use [UriTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriTemplate.html) with a template of the link you want provide in the email, fill the parameter values into a map and expand it. The base URL should be held in a configurable property.

Other approaches like using a link builder (e.g. [ControllerLinkBuilder](http://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/api/org/springframework/hateoas/mvc/ControllerLinkBuilder.html) included in [Spring HATEOAS](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-hateoas/0.20.x/reference/html/#fundamentals.obtaining-links.builder.methods)) will fail with the same root cause.

Comment: Also in my experience the only way is to configure the base URL in a configurable property